# trying to compare two email fields - page blanks out

Tags: php, forms

Right now, posting a snippet of what I wrote:

```
if (isset($_POST["email1"] != $_POST["email2"])) { 
  $email2Err = "please enter the same email address"; 
}
```

*Every* single time when I try to post the snippet above or a variation of it, it *literally* blanks out my page.

Question is, is the code I wrote above a good way to compare two email addresses via text fields?

And why does it blank out my entire page every time?

Here's a bit of further context if that's more helpful (let me know you want the *entire* page):

```
  <?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["nights"])) {
     $nightsErr = "# of nights are required";
   } else {
     $nights = test_input($_POST["nights"]);
   }

  if (empty($_POST["arrivals"])) {
     $arrivalsErr = "Time of arrival is required";
   } else {
     $arrivals = test_input($_POST["arrivals"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["male"])) {
     $maleErr = "# of people (gender female) required";
   } else {
     $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["female"])) {
     $femaleErr = "# of people (gender female) required";
   } else {
     $female = test_input($_POST["female"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["rooms"])) {
     $roomsErr = "# of rooms required";
   } else {
     $rooms = test_input($_POST["rooms"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["type"])) {
     $typeErr = "type of rooms required";
   } else {
     $type = test_input($_POST["type"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "name required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
     $addressErr = "address required";
   } else {
     $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["zip"])) {
     $zipErr = "zip required";
   } else {
     $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["telephone"])) {
     $telephoneErr = "telephone required";
   } else {
     $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["email1"])) {
     $email1Err = "email required";
   } else {
     $email1 = test_input($_POST["email1"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["email2"])) {
     $email2Err = "email2 required";
   } else {
     $email2 = test_input($_POST["email2"]);
   }

    if (isset($_POST["email1"] != $_POST["email2"])) { 
      $email2Err = "please enter the same email address"; 
   }    
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["email1"] != $_POST["email2"]))` that's not how it works.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, then how should I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing you and isn't the right syntax for what you want to achieve:

```
if (isset($_POST["email1"] != $_POST["email2"]))
```

What you need to do is to first check if it is set then check if both are (not) equal to, but it's best to use `!empty()`, then check if it is not equal to:

```
if (!empty($_POST["email1"]) && !empty($_POST["email2"])) {
     if ($_POST["email1"] != $_POST["email2"]) { 
       $email2Err = "Emails don't match. Please enter the same email address.";
   }
}
```

- Plus, make sure your form elements both have the right name attributes.

Also, a blank page can mean syntax errors.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 You're very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (isset($_POST["email1"]) && isset($_POST["email2"])) {
   if ($_POST["email1"] != $_POST["email2"]) { 
     $email2Err = "please enter the same email address";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is assigning by using a single equals to sign rather make it a double equals to sign,  I mean ==